# Codeigniter php: bootstrap modal view is sending empty array on submit

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have this bootstrap modal view:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <form method = "POST" action = "<?php echo base_url('Monitor/myfct') ?>">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add missed Tara or Harvest Product</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="font-noraml">
            Select event type
          </label>
       <div class="input-group">
            <select data-placeholder="Select" class="form-control chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
              <option value="Tara">
                Tara Machine
              </option>
              <option value="Harvest">
                Harvest Product Machine
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
         </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="font-noraml">
            Product list
          </label>
       <div class="input-group">
            <select id ="harvestAjaxData" data-placeholder="Select" class="form-control chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
            </select>
          </div>
         </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="font-noraml">
            Machine list
          </label>
       <div class="input-group">
            <select id ="machineAjaxData" data-placeholder="Select" class="form-control chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
            </select>
          </div>
         <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputimpurities">Impurities</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputimpurities" placeholder="Impurities" style="width:350px;">
  </div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputhumidity">Humidity</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputhumidity" placeholder="Humidity" style="width:350px;">
  </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Except first one, fields are completed on ajax call with dynamic data (coming from mysql tables) and 2 user input fields, and the controller function where I send that form is this one Monitor/myfct:

```
public function myfct() {
        $data= $this->input->post();
        print_r($data);
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
```

I use it to test my form submit, I get the javascript alert(so the call was successful), but the print $data comes with a empty Array, also tried to print $_POST, same output. What is wrong in my modal view? Should I put the name="" for the options?

ps. I should add how the options from ajax look like:

```
for(var i = 0; i< data.length;i++){

  $('#harvestAjaxData').append('<option value="'+data[i]['name']+'">'+data[i]['name']+'</option>');
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make the example a [mcve]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving name attributes to selects

Comment: That actually like I was suspected was the problem, thank you sir :)